# How to get working variables out of a function in F#

Tags: function, f#, local-variables

I have a function in F# , like:

```
let MyFunction x = 
    let workingVariable1 = x + 1
    let workingVariable2 = workingVariable1 + 1
    let y = workingVariable2 + 1
    y
```

Basically, `MyFunction` takes an input `x` and returns `y`. However, in the process of calculation, there are a few working variables (intermediate variables), and due to the nature of my work (civil engineering), I need to report all intermediate results. How should I store all working variables of the function ?

Comment: if by "report" you just talk about logging in some sort then this is a typical case for the [writer monad](http://www.learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more)

Comment: Another option could be to build an expression tree of the computation and then in the generic evaluation function collect all intermediate values and report them in a fashion you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then there are several options:

```
let MyFunction1 x = 
    let workingVariable1 = x + 1
    let workingVariable2 = workingVariable1 + 1
    let y = workingVariable2 + 1
    y,workingVariable1,workingVariable2

MyFunction1 2 |> printfn "%A"

type OneType()=
    member val Y = 0 with get,set
    member val WV1 = 0 with get,set
    member val WV2 = 0 with get,set

    override this.ToString() =
        sprintf "Y: %d; WV1: %d; WV2: %d\n" this.Y this.WV1 this.WV2

let MyFunction2 x = 
    let workingVariable1 = x + 1
    let workingVariable2 = workingVariable1 + 1
    let y = workingVariable2 + 1
    new OneType(Y=y,WV1=workingVariable1,WV2=workingVariable2)

MyFunction2 2 |> printfn "%A"
```

Out:

```
(5, 3, 4)
Y: 5; WV1: 3; WV2: 4
```

http://ideone.com/eYNwYm

In the first function uses the tuple:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx

The second native data type.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233205.aspx

Comment: I like the first option, however it has a drawback. If there are 10-20 working variables, then the returned set has 10-20 values, it'd be hard to know which is which.  The second option is similar to what I would do in C# or VB.NET, I'd create a class that has all working variables, and make the function returns an instance of that class.  But this second option seems like OOP  - is that approach common in  Functional Programming ?

Comment: Or use a record, which is more idiomatic F# and less boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what kind of "report" your are expecting. Is this a log of intermediate values ? How long time this log should be kept ? etc. etc This is my attempt from what I understand. It is not ideal solution because it allows to report **values** of intermediate steps but without knowing exactly which expression has generated the intermediate value (I think that you would like to know that a value `n` was an output of `workingVariable1 = x + 1` expression).

So my solution is based on [Computation Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd233182.aspx). Computation expression are a kind of F# "monads".

First you need to define a computation expression :

```
type LoggingBuilder() =
    let log p = printfn "intermediate result %A" p

    member this.Bind(x, f) = 
        log x
        f x

    member this.Return(x) = 
        x
```

Next we create an instance of computation expression builder :

```
let logIntermediate = new LoggingBuilder()
```

Now you can rewrite your original function like this:

```
let loggedWorkflow x = 
    logIntermediate
        {
            let! workingVariable1 = x + 1
            let! workingVariable2 = workingVariable1 + 1
            let! y = workingVariable2 + 1
            return y,workingVariable1,workingVariable2
        }
```

If you run `loggedWorkflow` function passing in 10 you get this result :

```
> loggedWorkflow 10;;
intermediate result 11
intermediate result 12
intermediate result 13
val it : int * int * int = (13, 11, 12)
```

As I said your intermediate values are logged, however you're not sure which line of code is responsible for.

We could however enchance a little bit to get the FullName of the type with a corresponding line of code. We have to change a little our computation expression builder :

```
member this.Bind(x, f) = 
        log x (f.GetType().FullName)
        f x
```

and a log function to :

```
let log p f = printfn "intermediate result %A %A" p f
```

If you run again `loggedWorkflow` function passing in 10 you get this result (this is from my script run in FSI) :

```
intermediate result 11 "FSI_0003+loggedWorkflow@34"
intermediate result 12 "FSI_0003+loggedWorkflow@35-1"
intermediate result 13 "FSI_0003+loggedWorkflow@36-2"
```

**This is a hack** but we get some extra information about where the expressions like `workingVariable1 = x + 1` were definied (in my case it is "FSI_") and on which line of code (@34, @35-1). If your code changes and this is very likely to happen, your intermediate result if logged for a long time will be false. Note that I have not tested it outside of FSI and don't know if lines of code are included in every case.

I'm not sure if we can get an expression name (like `workingVariable1 = x + 1`) to log from computation expression. I think it's not possible.

Note: Instead of log function you coud define some other function that persist this intermediate steps in a durable storage or whatever.

**UPDATE**

I've tried to came up with a different solution and it is not very easy. However I might have hit a compromise. Let me explain. You can't get a name of value is bound to inside a computation expression. So we are not able to log for example for expression `workingVariable1 = x + 1` that `"'workingVariable1' result is 2"`. Let say we pass into our computation expression an extra name of intermediate result like that :

```
let loggedWorkflow x = 
    logIntermediate
        {
            let! workingVariable1 = "wk1" @@ x + 1
            let! workingVariable2 = "wk2" @@ workingVariable1 + 1
            let! y = "y" @@ workingVariable2 + 1
            return y,workingVariable1,workingVariable2
        }
```

As you can see before `@@` sign we give the name of the intermediate result so `let! workingVariable1 = "wk1" @@ x + 1` line will be logged as "wk1".

We need then an extra type which would store a name and a value of the expression :

```
type NamedExpression<'T> = {Value:'T ; Name: string}
```

Then we have to redefine an infix operator `@@` we use une computation expression :

```
let (@@) name v = {Value = v; Name = name}
```

This operator just takes left and right part of the expression and wraps it within `NamedExpression<'T>` type.

We're not done yet. We have to modify the Bind part of our computation expression builder :

```
member this.Bind(x, f) =
        let {Name = n; Value = v} = x
        log v n
        f v
```

First we deconstruct the `NamedExpression<'T>` value into name and wraped value. We log it and apply the function `f` to the unwrapped value `v`. Log function looks like that :

```
let log p n = printfn "'%s' has intermediate result of : %A" n p
```

Now when you run the workflow `loggedWorkflow 10;;` you get the following result :

```
'wk1' has intermediate result of : 11
'wk2' has intermediate result of : 12
'y' has intermediate result of : 13
```

Maybe there are better way to do that, something with compiler services or so, but this is the best attempt I could do so far.

Comment: by "report" I meant the log of all working variables.  It is similar to , you are given a math question with given input, and you are required to calculate the result. However, the math teacher would sometimes want to check the steps you've gone through...Thanks Tomasz, I used to use a global array to store all working variables of all functions in VB.NET. But i don't know how or whether I should do the same in F# as it might violate the functional rules

Comment: So generaly you would store it like the name of working variable as a key and it's associated value ?

Comment: yes - with VB.NET, for each of my program, I usually have a global array, and have Enum to store the variable names associated with the index of the array.

Comment: Ok, I'm thinking about something. I'll be back to you asap

Comment: I've added another solution to my answer. Maybe this might be better for you

Answer (score 1):

It's not very "functional" way, but you can use mutable variable to store intermediate results:

```
let mutable workingVariable1 = 0
let mutable workingVariable2 = 0

let MyFunction x = 
    workingVariable1 <- x + 1
    workingVariable2 <- workingVariable1 + 1
    let y = workingVariable2 + 1
    y
```

Comment: it's not only not functional - it's a high risk operation (global variables, not thread-safe at all, ...) and a definite anti-pattern :(

Comment: To avoid global variables we can tag it as private - `let mutable private workingVariable1 = 0`. Carsten, thanks for you comment, I'm not aiming to raise a discussion here, just want to give N.T.C. yet another option to consider.